# Can I restrict root user from installing or Uninstalling Packages

Tags: software-installation

I want to restrict root user from installing packages

Comment: XY problem, clearly. What led you to believe you need to restrict root from installing packages? What is the purpose?

Comment: The "root user" is just a concept, notionally the user with permissions to do stuff like installing and uninstalling packages. Who or what do you want to restrict exactly?

Answer (score 27):

## No.

`root` is the super user. It can do everything by definition. No way to put any restrictions on the system that couldn't be reverted with `root` rights again.

Comment: If @Byte Commander's answer solved your question, please accept it.

Comment: Agreed but it is possible to stop the admin in a virtual operating system from installing packages :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't exactly understand what you mean, would you mind to elaborate your thought, maybe in a separate answer?

Comment: I work in small company where all Users  have Root  access so everyone can install/remove  what they want do So My Question can we restrict  this

Comment: @Rkb well there you go wrong. Have the owner of the company revoke those admin permissions.  There should be 1 admin and 1 backup for the admin.

Comment: It should be possible to administrate those systems with local admin accounts if you use something like [Puppet](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/puppet.html). Just explicitly state that the users are not allowed to remove the Puppet client through which you can remotely control the machines and repeatedly check that all clients are still there. Then you can set up automatic tasks that ensure specific software is (not) installed. I guess that might be the most control you can have over machines with local admin accounts.

Comment: @ByteCommander wont work for this question. But an admin on Ubuntu with an Ubuntu in a virtual machine can monitor the admin in the virtual machine

Comment: If people want to get around puppet they will... there should not be that many root users.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, of course. But in a company environment, you should be able to force the employees to leave Puppet intact by having them sign a document or whatever.You can remotely verify whether Puppet still runs on all clients and there should be enough trust towards the employees for that. If not, the only solution is really to not give them local admin accounts. However, as they have physical access to the machines, they could also theoretically get root rights without having an admin account granted.

Comment: @RKB I read as far as "where all users have root access" and then I had to go into a quiet room to scream for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you implement [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control):

> Role-based-access-control (RBAC) is a policy neutral access control
>   mechanism defined around roles and privileges. The components of RBAC
>   such as role-permissions, user-role and role-role relationships make
>   it simple to perform user assignments. A study by NIST has
>   demonstrated that RBAC addresses many needs of commercial and
>   government organizations. RBAC can be used to facilitate
>   administration of security in large organizations with hundreds of
>   users and thousands of permissions. Although RBAC is different from
>   MAC and DAC access control frameworks, it can enforce these policies
>   without any complication. Its popularity is evident from the fact that
>   many products and businesses are using it directly or indirectly.

See [How to implement and modify policies for Role-based access control on Ubuntu Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350834/how-to-implement-and-modify-policies-for-role-based-access-control-on-ubuntu-lin)

Under RBAC, there is no real "root" user as normally thought of.  What's normally thought of as "root" becomes a role, and you don't have to give that role permissions to install software.

However, implementing RBAC isn't trivial, and in the end you still have to have at least a few system administrators that have full access to everything.  Someone has to have access to everything in order to configure the RBAC roles.

In my experience, RBAC is only really useful for large organizations with a lot of system administrators who have to do widely different things.

In the US, RBAC may also be needed in order to meet legal requirements imposed by things like [HIPAA](https://www.google.com/search?q=hipaa%20rbac) and [Sarbanes-Oxley](https://www.google.com/search?q=hipaa%20sarbanes%20oxley).

In your case, RBAC is almost certainly not worth the administrative overhead.

But it most certainly is possible to prevent "root" from installing software.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is a way to avoid giving people root access but instead giving them roles that allow them to do specific tasks they need, right? It's not about preventing root from doing anything. And with physical access anyone can gain root privileges anyway, as a reminder.

Comment: @ByteCommander There is no root user under RBAC to prevent from doing anything - the root user can't do anything because it's not there. There might be a role called root that can be configured to do what a root user normally is capable of, but there doesn't have to be. RBAC is specifically designed so that no one person can access or control everything. OP's real problem is they gave out root to everyone. RBAC could take some power back, but administering RBAC is a nightmare. IMO OP should either take root away or tell users "You get root, we won't fix it". RBAC is really for HIPAA/SOX.

Comment: (cont) Every time I've dealt with RBAC, it was painful.  If you're not required to use it, I'd say **DON'T**.  But it would do what the OP wanted - prevent "root" users from installing software while still allowing privileged access of other types.  But at the cost of lots of sysadmin man-hours, and lots of frustrated users.

Comment: Rkb would be better off revoking permissions and use the sudoers file to add permissions to commands users need.